# Closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I've got a very straightforward question : if $T : B \rightarrow B$ is a linear continuous operator and $B$ is a Banach space, is $T$ a closed operator?

This is obviously true in finite dimension, but I'm not sure what can happen in infinite dimension. Maybe it can't get "too bad" if $B$ is a Banach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) If closed means the image of every closed set is closed: No.

If this was true, any injective bounded operator with dense range would have to be surjective, whence invertible on a Banach space by the Banach isomorphism theorem. The compact diagonal operator $T(x_n)=(x_n/n)$ on $\ell^2$ is a natural counterexample.

---

2) If closed means the operator is closed, that is its graph is closed in $B\times B$: Yes.

Assume $(x_n,Tx_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$ in $X\times X$, that is $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $Tx_n\rightarrow y$ in $X$. By continuity of $T$, $Tx_n\rightarrow Tx$. By uniqueness of a limit in a metric space, $Tx=y$. So $(x,y)=(x,Tx)$ belongs to the graph of $T$.

Comment: it seems to me this proof works even if $f$ is non linear. does this mean that for any continuous $f$, the image of a closed set is closed ?

Comment: Closed operator does not mean that image of closed set is closed here. Closed means that the graph of the operator is closed.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, the graph of a continuous function $f:X\longrightarrow X$ is closed when $X$ is a metric space. That's the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ for the continuous map $(x,y)\longmapsto y-f(x)$.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki So you are Kevin? Also, please do not deface the question. Ask another one instead.

Comment: @julien I think he is mixing up the two definitions of closedness, not asking if the graph is closed.

Comment: The question has been changed in the middle!

Comment: @julien : well, I am busted =) 
yes, sorry. I asked the question with another pseudo because I was somewhat ashamed of not remembering  this basic fact in operator theory (it's been a long time). not very classy but I saw in the meta that it was not against the rules of this site. i changed the question because the other formulation was not what I wanted to ask.

Comment: I'm sorry to have changed the question (due to a miscomprehension of the term "closed operator"). if you think it is approppriate I will accept an answer here and ask another question correctly

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I answered the new question as well.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki You're welcome. It is fine to use another pseudo to ask questions one would be embarrassed asking otherwise. I understand many people do that. But who can identify you as "Glougloubarbaki" anyway?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is closed. Look at the definition of closedness, it is a weaker definition than continuity.

If $T$ is continuous, then for every sequence $x_{n}$ in the domain of $T$ converging to some $x$ in domain of $T$, the sequence $Tx_{n}$ has to converge and has to converge to $Tx$. The sequence $Tx_{n}$ has no choice!

And what is the definition of closed? If $x_{n}$ is sequence in domain of $T$ converging to some $x$ in domain of $T$, then we only require that *if* the sequence $Tx_{n}$ converges, then it should converge to the "correct" limit, that is $Tx$. But it may not converge at all.
In case of conitnuity, however, the poor sequence $Tx_{n}$ *has* to converge and converge to $Tx$. Thus, continuity implies closedness.